# why is it showing as decimal.InvalidOperation error in azure synapse?

Tags: azure, azure-synapse

While calculating the percentage, it is not able to do the division, giving an error stating decimal invalid operator.

```
%%pyspark
ss['Inv_InvAmtLateby6_30Days_GC_perc']=ss['Inv_InvAmtLateby6_30Days_GC']/ss['Inv_InvAmt_GC']
```

Error:

```
decimal.InvalidOperation: [<class 'decimal.DivisionUndefined'>]
```

Comment: Make sure there are no exceptions happening on account of division by 0 i.e. no cells in the ss['Inv_InvAmt_GC'] which is 0. You should handle this appropriately,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, you may need to handle division by 0 - although the error with the term 'undefined' makes me think the 0 may actually be in the numerator, not the denominator - have you accounted for 0's in both places?